# Dockerizing a react project

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, containers, vite

I'm trying to dockerize my project with the next dockerfile in prod

```
# Etapa de construcción
FROM node:alpine as build

# Establecer el directorio de trabajo dentro del contenedor
WORKDIR /app

# Copiar los archivos del proyecto al contenedor
COPY . .

# Instalar las dependencias utilizando Yarn
RUN yarn install

# Compilar la aplicación React
RUN yarn build

# Etapa de producción
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copiar los archivos de compilación de la etapa de construcción al servidor web Nginx
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copiar la configuración personalizada de Nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Exponer el puerto en el que la aplicación se ejecutará (puerto 4000)
EXPOSE 4001

# Comando para iniciar el servidor Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

But when the image is being built, this problem appears:

```
[internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                                      0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 826B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                                           0.9s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18                                                                                                0.9s
 => [build 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:18@sha256:aa329c613f0067755c0787d2a3a9802c7d95eecdb927d62b910ec1d28689882f                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 7.00kB                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:6a2f8b28e45c4adea04ec207a251fd4a2df03ddc930f782af51e315ebc76e9a9                      0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [build 3/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                  0.6s
 => [build 4/6] RUN wget -q --spider http://google.com                                                                                                    0.9s
 => [build 5/6] RUN yarn install --network-timeout 100000                                                                                               825.0s
 => => # info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...                                                                           
 => => # info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...                                                                           
 => => # info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

I tried to increase the network-timeout but nothing. I also tried to prove the connection from the dockerfile with

```
RUN wget -q --spider http://google.com
```

and there is connection but I don´t have an idea what else could be, because the problem continues. I would like to get help with this problem, please?